# Adding a new aspect with a User property

Tags: content-management-system, alfresco, alfresco-share

Is it possible to add a property inside a new aspect that will hold a User from Alfresco's users ?

It will be used to input the User who's responsabile/authorizer of a document having a defined aspect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you've defined the same field twice. First as a **d:text** property and the second is an **association**.

In your model you've defined

```
<property name="txm:vacationPerson">
   <title>Nom et prénom</title>
   <type>d:text</type>
</property>
```

And as association you've defined:

```
    <associations>
        <association name="txm:vacationPerson">
            <title>Assignee</title>
            <source>
                <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                <many>false</many>
            </source>
            <target>
                <class>cm:person</class>
                <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                <many>false</many>
            </target>
        </association>
    </associations>
```

So it's rendering the first field as text and the second field isn't rendered anymore.
Remove the first **d:text** property or rename it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and you may choose to use either an assocation or a property.  Assuming you want users  to pick the person manually, I'd go for the association since the default controls provided by share support picking a person out of the box.

Here is  a sample aspect showing both - a property and an association to hold the user.

```
<aspect name="your:assignee">
  <title>Your Aspect</title>
  <properties>
    <property name="your:assigedPersonUsername">
      <title>Owner</title>
      <type>d:text</type>
    </property>
  </properties>
  <associations>
    <association name="your:assignedPerson">
      <title>Assignee</title>
      <source>
        <mandatory>false</mandatory>
        <many>false</many>
      </source>
      <target>
        <class>cm:person</class>
        <mandatory>false</mandatory>
        <many>false</many>
      </target>
    </association>
  </associations>
</aspect>
```

Comment: It is not working: assigedPersonUsername is displayed as a free text input, and there's no other option to choose from persons

Comment: Fourat, Andreas is showing you the content model, which is correct. If you are testing the property via Share, you'll also need to create form configuration in share-config-custom.xml that tells Alfresco how to display the association in Share.

Comment: You need to be aware that you cannot search for an assoc... Alfresco often uses the username-d:text-property to be able to search for your user-property.

Comment: Jeff, i've already updated the share-config-custom.xml file, maybe i'm wrong doing it, here's my files: model= http://pastebin.com/GVCYm7q5 and share-config= http://pastebin.com/6nZJ6gYi